# Etymology of "by half"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin of “Too Clever by Half”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49107/origin-of-too-clever-by-half)

We say "by half" to emphasize the degree of something in an idiomatic way, and often as a slight on the person we're talking about.  For example,

> He's too clever by half.  You're too complacent by half.  He was too good a teacher by half for that school.

How did this phrase originate?  What relevance does "half" have to do with the superlative nature of an attribute?

Comment: @Daniel: I *would* have been first to closevote the dup - but I spent too long by half perusing my own answer to the original to make sure it was up to snuff!